# Using kubernetes/client-node lib

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-apiserver

I have kubernetes cluster on my GCP platform and I want to get Node's list in my cluster by using client-node lib.

```
    const cluster = {
        name: 'my-cluster-1',
        server: 'https://endpoints.googleapis.com',
    };

    const user = {
        name: 'myemail@gmail.com',
        password: 'mypassword',
    };
    const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
    kc.loadFromClusterAndUser(cluster, user);

    const k8sApi = kc.makeApiClient(k8s.CoreV1Api);

    k8sApi.listNode()
        .then((res) => {
            console.log('RESULT: ' + JSON.stringify(res));
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
        });
```

But this code fails with `Bad Gateway` message.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes client lib expects the Kubernetes user credentials which are not the same as the Gmail/Gsuite credentials.

Get the user credentials for cluster using `gcloud container clusters get-credentials [CLUSTER_NAME]`

and then load the config as below

```
const kc = new k8s.KubeConfig();
kc.loadFromDefault();
```